KDE Plasma Left-Alt key not working as expected in certain applications
I have noticed that my left-alt key not working in certain applications on my Arch Linux KDE plasma setup. The key still works with keyboard shortcuts (such as Alt-Tab), and the xev tool in the terminal picks up the left-alt and displays the output:
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
root 0x53c, subw 0x0, time 871346, (-160,182), root:(710,624),
state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

which looks correct to me.
A specific cases I've found where the left-alt key isn't working correctly is with Firefox. Pressing either of the alt keys in Firefox should show the menu bar along the top (showing menus such as File, Edit, View, etc). With my current issue it is only showing when I press the right alt, but should work with the left as well.
However, when using the left alt key in a firefox shortcut, such as alt+left arrow key, it does work.
The incorrect behavior is not limited to Firefox; another case I've noticed is the game War Thunder not picking up the left alt key.
This problem is only present while using X11 with Plasma, if I switch to using Wayland (or Windows 10) the left alt key works completely fine. But switching to Wayland isn't an acceptable work around for me, as I have use many programs that don't work well with it.
I don't know specifically when this became an issue. With the Alt-Tab shortcut still working I don't think I noticed it straight away. When I did start to notice it I assumed it was a bug in the application I was using, until I started noticing it across several applications. So I couldn't tell you in which update this started becoming an issue
The keyboard model that the system is set for (according to Plamsas system settings) is "Generic | Generic 104-key PC", with the layout being English (US), with the variant set to default.
The keyboard I have is a "Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard". However, I have tested it with other keyboards they problem remains.
Microsoft page for my keyboard model
My system Specs:
Operating System: Arch Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 6.0.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.2.0
Qt Version: 6.7.0
Kernel Version: 6.6.30-2-lts (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT
Manufacturer: ASUS

I don't know which logs (if any) you guys would want to see. If there are any let me know and I'll find and post them.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

How are you using the left Alt in firefox? Is there a specific shortcut you use with firefox that doesn't work? Is it something like left Alt + click to drag the window? Something else? Can you give us something specific we can try in case we can reproduce this?

@terdon Pressing Alt in Firefox should show the menu bar along the top (showing menus such as File, Edit, View, etc). With my current issue it is only showing when I press the right alt, but should work with the left as well.

Ah, OK. Please [edit] that into your question. I just tested (Arch, Cinnamon, Xorg) and I have the exact inverse: right alt does nothing and left alt makes the menu appear. Which makes sense since by default the right Alt is the AltGr key. Could you have switched the Alt keys around? And what keyboard layout are you using? Have you checked for any firefox-specific shortcuts that might be capturing the keypress? (please [edit] the info into the question, don't answer in a comment, so that others can find it easily)

@terdon I have now added that information into the post. I was surprised to find the Firefox short cuts using the left alt key work, just not pressing it individually.
I suppose a workaround I could do is to remap and swap the alt keys around. It annoys me though not knowing why this is acting up.

Thanks for the edit. Can you tell us your layout (e.g. "English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)", you should be able to see that in the KDE keyboard settings) though? I don't think the hardware will be relevant, but the layout might be. Especially whether you use a layout with dead keys or not.

@terdon done! just using the English (US) with the default variant
